# Chef Server returning 404 for knife commands from Chef workstation

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, push

I am trying to set up Push jobs on existing Chef server.

`knife ssl check` , `knife client list` and `knife node list` returns success, however:

`knife node status`returns HTTP error 404:

ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found ...

Checked knife.rb on workstation and it looks good.
if the problem is on ORGANIZATION_NAME OR CHEF_SERVER_URL then it should fail for all knife commands.
but I am getting response for knife node list .

Below is my knife configuration

```
   current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    log_level                :info
    log_location             STDOUT
    node_name                "NODE1"
    chef_server_url          "https://SERVER_NAME_FQDN/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NAME"
    validation_client_name   "ORGANIZATION_NAME-validator"
    client_key               "#{current_dir}/CLIENT1.pem"
    cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running `knife node status [<node> <node> ...]` per the syntax https://docs.chef.io/push_jobs.html#node-status and getting the error?

Ensure the push jobs client is installed and running on the node.

On your node, ensure ports `10000-10003` are open so the node can communicate with the chef server.